# Closing multiple new form [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with my sw: i have three forms: the main form(A), a secondary form (B) and third form (C). The form A must be always visibile and usable, the form B opening from form A and the form C opening form the form B.
I need to open multiple instance of form C (i do not know how much instance are), i'm using this code in a command button on form B:

```
            Dim newform As New modifica_normale
            newform.LoadOrders(commessa_da_modificare, id_da_modificare, False)
            newform.Show()
```

When the form B is close i need to close all of multiple instance of form C, so in the closing event i've tried to put:

```
            modifica_normale.Close()
```

but do not work.
I know that i can define newform as global variable and call newform.close(), but i don't know the number of newform that the user will open.

Thanks, Pietro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will only close the common instance of the form and not each newly instantiated form object:

```
 modifica_normale.Close()
```

Instead you could try adding the forms to a forms collection as you create each form.
Create a form level list on form B.

```
 Dim currentForms As List(Of Form) = New List(Of Form)
```

Add to it each time an instance of form C is created

```
Dim fNew As New modifica_normale
currentForms.Add(fNew)
```

When you want to close them, loop back through the forms collection closing each instance.

```
For Each frmCheck As Form In currentForms
    frmCheck.Close
Next
```

Comment: An explanation as to why the OP's code doesn't work would be nice

Comment: (I hane no idea how to add code in the comment) it works, but when the first form are closed the form each return an error: "the collection have been changed". I solved the problem by this orrible way:


            before:
            For Each frmCheck As Form In Application.OpenForms
                If frmCheck.Name = form_name Then
                    frmCheck.Close()
                    GoTo before
                End If
            Next

Comment: thank you! i didn't know the list metod. I can use it for many other situations.

Comment: could you se here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633067/timer-issue-vb-net