# Timer issue [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, timer

my situation is explained here:
[Closing multiple new form [VB.NET]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559484/closing-multiple-new-form-vb-net/32559568#32559568)

i have three forms: the main form(A), a secondary form (B) and third form (C). The form A must be always visibile and usable, the form B opening from form A and the form C opening form the form B. I open multiple instance of form C (i do not know how much instance are) and i'm using this code in a command button on form B:

```
        Dim newform As New modifica_normale
        newform.LoadOrders(commessa_da_modificare, id_da_modificare, False)
        newform.Show()
```

now the problem is: 
when i close the form B all of forms C are closing correctly, but the timer on form C do not stop when the form B and the form C are closed.
I've already tried to put, on form C closing:

```
Private Sub modifica_normale_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed

    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Dispose()
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

the code that i'm using to close all of forms C is (the code is in the formB.closed event):

```
   before:
        For Each frmCheck As Form In Application.OpenForms
            If frmCheck.Name = modifica_normale Then
                frmCheck.Close()
                GoTo before
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Please, update your question by including a clear and comprehensive description of the problem (an external reference to a similar situation is not enough).

Comment: How do you close the C instances? How do you verify that the timer still runs?

Comment: because the timer call a resource on the same form and it isn't avaible. I've verified it with debug and my error log.

Comment: Put it in Form C's `FormClosing` event.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What kind of resource are you accessing? How do you create the timer? Does the Closed handler get called? It is not necessary to dispose of the Form in its Closed event handler, nor of the timer. And get rid of that `Goto`.

Comment: @Mort what have i to put in the C's form closing event?

Comment: @PietroZ.Timer1.Enabled=False

Comment: @NicoSchertler, i will rid Goto as explained to me Mort in previous post. The timer is an object created on C's form.

Comment: @Mort i've just tried: nothing change.

Comment: @NicoSchertler the resource is a backgroundworker that try to connect to a MySQL database, but the connection isn't aviable because the form is closed

Comment: @PietroZ. then as Nico says, something else is holding the forms open. I've tested this in my test project and it works correctly without even having to disable the timer in FormClosing. You must have another reference to the form.

Comment: @Mort thanks, i check my code for some error. I've tried to debug all program loading and i see that the timer1 on form C start when form B opening. But i've checked and i never create or call timer1 before C's form opening

Comment: @Mort. I solved my problem. it is very very strange. I set timer1.enabled=false on graphic setting. After i've added timer1.enabled=true on C's form.load. it seems that the graphic setting enable the timer on application start, i didn't know it.